# Equivalence Relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let H be the set of all living human beings.

1. Define a relation $R_1$ on H by saying that $h_1R_1h_2$if $h_1$ and $h_2$ have at least one parent in common. Is $R_1$ an equivalence relation?
2. Suppose we define another relation $R_2$ on H by saying $h_1R_2h_2$ if $h_1$ and $h_2$ have the same mother. Is $R_2$ an equivalence relation?

---

1. My answer is No. Because $h_1$ mother is not related to $h_3$ mother.

Is my reasoning for 1 right? How should I answer 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A relation is an equivalence relation if and only if it satisfies three properties:

(1) **symmetry** ($h_1Rh_1$ for any $h_1$),
(2) **reflexivity** ($h_1Rh_2$ implies $h_2Rh_1$), and
 
(3) **transitivity** ($h_1Rh_2$ and $h_2Rh_3$ imply $h_1Rh_3$)

Both $h1$ and $h2$ are clearly reflexive (you have parents in common with yourself) and symmetric (if I have a parent in common with you, then you have a parent in common with me), but as you noted $h1$ is not transitive: we can imagine a situation where $h1$ and $h2$ have the same mother but not the same father, $h2$ and $h3$ have the same father but not the same mother. $R_2$, on the other hand, is transitive, so $R_2$ is an equivalence relation.

It should be noted that $R_1$ not being transitive (and more in general, relation properties) depends on the set you are considering. It's safe to say that the scenario that served as a counterexample happened somewhere on this planet, but on a smaller set $R_1$ could be transitive (for example, it might be so among the people you know personally).

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) on the topic is well written, and has more examples and explanations about equivalency relations.

Comment: Clear explanation and the link to the wiki is most helpful.